# LightSwitch HTML <input type="number"> jQuery mobile field not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have the following custom control render code:

```
myapp.AddEditProduct.Quantity_render = function (element, contentItem) {
$("<input type='number'>").appendTo(element);
};
```

I can't seem to get the jQuery number field to show the up down arrow buttons. This is VS2013 LightSwitch with jQuery Mobile 1.3.0. This results in a regular text input field. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding this to the function `$("[type=number]").textinput();`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you wanted me to add this. I can't find anything on textinput() on Google.

Comment: It didn't work in IE (my debug browser (not by choice)) but the number field works in Chrome :)

Answer (score 1):

I used this and work for me on the posRender event:

```
myapp.consulta_negocio.year_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(element).find("input").get(0).type = "number";
}
```